# Ace editor with an onchange event is not working

Tags: javascript, onchange, ace-editor

I'm working on a code playground using the [Ace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_(editor)) editor, and I am trying to use Ace editor onChange, but nothing happens when I type.

My code is

```html
<style>
    html {
        padding: 0px
    }
    #editor {
        border-radius: 5px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%
    }
</style>

<a href="#" onclick="update()">go</a>
    <div id="editor" onChange="update()">
        function foo(items) {
            var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
            return x;
        }
    </div>
    <script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"
            type="text/javascript"
            charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
        editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
            update()
        });
    </script>

    <script>;
        new function update()
        {
            var ace = editor.getSession().getValue();
            var divecho = document.getElementById("output");
            divecho.innerHTML = ace
        }
    </script>
    <div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: shouldn't it just be  `editor.on('change', function() {
update()
});`

Comment: I was going off of http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor which has `Editor.on("change"...);`

Comment: @Teemu I hate JQuery, don't u? Everybody uses it and doesn't mention it when they answer. EDIT: k I try not to use it that much either

Comment: I doubt native `onchange` registers only changes in form elements, like `select` and `input`. What is the real element modified by Ace? Your div is just a wrapper. Though the API itself contains a custom event, just as epascarello has brought to the daylight in his comment above. No, I don't hate jQuery, though I don't need it either...

Comment: @Teemu ACE is actually based off a modified JQuery

Comment: I tried @epascarello's method but it didn't work.
...Maybe I need JQuery after all

Comment: @teemu Yeah. Yeah I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new function update()
```

should be

```
function update()
```

Also it is not wise to use ace as a local variable when it is a global.