# How to listen for and react to Ace Editor change events

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

What would be an example of how the *on change* event works in ACE Editor (https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor), with a simple `getValue()` when the there is an *on change* event and send the new text to a *div*?

Answer (score 23):

See https://jsfiddle.net/ralf_htp/hbxhgdr1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/revathskumar/rY37e/

#### HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Editor</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="#" onclick="update()">go</a>
      <div id="editor" onChange="update()">function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="output">Output is here (click 'go' and write HTML and js in the editor) </div>
  <div class="text-center">---End of editor---</div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
  update()
});

function update() //writes in <div> with id=output
{
  var val = editor.getSession().getValue();
  var divecho = document.getElementById("output");
  divecho.innerHTML = val;
}
```

The function `update()` implements the `onChange` event that is associated with the editor. If the **go-link** is clicked and then a character is written in the editor, the *update()-function* outputs the content of the editor in the `<div>` with `id = output` as HTML (innerHTML)

#### CSS

```css
#editor {
  /** Setting height is also important, otherwise the editor won’t show up **/
  height: 300px;
}

#output {
  height: 100px;
}
```

**https://ace.c9.io/**, section **Listening to Events**

See also this question: *[Ace editor with an onchange event is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011386/ace-editor-onchange-not-working)*

Comment: Minor suggestion: when binding to the "change" event, the update function can directly be passed without wrapping it in an extra function : `editor.getSession().on('change', update);`.

Comment: The https://ace.c9.io/ link is (effectively) broken.