# Ace editor key binding on focus only

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Ace editor is only a small part of my application. I would like the key binding to only work when the editor is on focus. Are there simple solutions?

The documentation is unfortunately not very detailed.

Comment: Can you be more explicit ? Are you looking for ace editor to receive notifications from other parts of your code ? What kind of notifications ? Write code automatically on specific coursor or change settings to ace or what kind ? Or [how to listen for events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732051/how-to-listen-for-and-react-to-ace-editor-change-events) from Ace editor (in this case Ace editor has the focus).

Comment: all ace editor keybinding already work only when ace is focused. ace doesn't add global keybindings.

Comment: @auser Now I see that my problem is local. ctrl+z and ctrl+shift+z events are caught even when ace code is not in focus. I'm trying to encapsulate the problem and perhaps I'll add to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.